# jdk 8 does not allow string in switch statement ?? why

Tags: java

```
error:
Cannot switch on a value of type String for source level below 1.7. Only convertible int values or enum constants are permitted code.
```

Here is an example:

```
String typeOfDay;
         switch (dayOfWeekArg) {
             case "Monday":
                 typeOfDay = "Start of work week";
                 break;
             case "Tuesday":
             case "Wednesday":
             case "Thursday":
                 typeOfDay = "Midweek";
                 break;
             case "Friday":
                 typeOfDay = "End of work week";
                 break;
             case "Saturday":
             case "Sunday":
                 typeOfDay = "Weekend";
                 break;
             default:
                 throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid day of the week: " + dayOfWeekArg);
         }
```

Comment: Please format your code using the "code" tool of the editor!

Comment: How do you compile your code? using plain `javac`? Or `IDE` (which one) ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
Cannot switch on a value of type String for source level below 1.7
```

You aren't using jdk 8. You either need to update java or fix the compiler compliance level of your IDE.

To change compiler compliance level in **Eclipse**:

Open Window > Preferences > Java > Compiler

Change the **Compiler compliance level** under "JDK Compliance" to 1.8

---

To change the source level in **Netbeans**:

Right-click the Libraries node in the Project view and choose Properties.

Choose "Sources" and set the **Source Level** to 1.8

---

To change the project bytecode version in **IntelliJ IDEA**:

Open File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Java Compiler

Set the **Project bytecode version** to 1.8

Answer (score 1):

It's highly recommend you use `if ("Monday".equals(dayOfWeekArg))` instead of switch. Because it support all JDKs. And nowadays, most of applications are running on JDK 1.7.

Comment: " And nowadays, most of applications are running on JDK 1.7." which is quite worrying since 1.7 reached its end of life for the general public (https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_7.xml)